# Make part of the code sleep for a number of minutes until the condition is met

Tags: java

This is part of the bigger code and with this part of code, if the condition is not met I want the code to wait or sleep for a number of minutes until the condition is met then continue.

The game odds change all the time and it might happen that the odds are low or high and they don't meet the condition or I may add another team that meet the condition later. So I want the code to wait for like 45 minutes and check again. If the condition is not met wait again but executes until the condition is met. I'm just stuck here Pl ease help.

```
    if(date_time[0] >= day && date_time[1] >= month && gameCurr_time_comp1 >= 10 && new_left_odds[0] >= 2.00 && new_left_odds[0] <= 2.4)      {
     System.out.println("PLACE TEAM ON INDEX 0 IF ALL CONDITIONS ARE MET:" + "\n" + matches[0] + "\n");    

     currentTeam = matches[0];
     currentGame = matches2[0];
      }

     else if(date_time[0] >= day && date_time[1] >= month && gameCurr_time_comp1 >= 10 && new_right_odds[0] >= 2.00 && new_right_odds[0] <= 2.4)    {
     System.out.println("PLACE TEAM ON INDEX 1 IF ALL CONDITIONS ARE MET:" + "\n" + matches[1] + "\n");     

     currentTeam = matches[1];
     currentGame = matches2[0];
     }

     else if(date_time[4] >= day && date_time[5] >= month && gameCurr_time_comp2 >= 10 && new_left_odds[1] >= 2.00 && new_left_odds[1] <= 2.4)    {
     System.out.println("PLACE TEAM ON INDEX 2 IF ALL CONDITIONS ARE MET:" + "\n" + matches[2] + "\n");     

     currentTeam = matches[2];
     currentGame = matches2[1];
     }

     else if(date_time[4] >= day && date_time[5] >= month && gameCurr_time_comp2 >= 10 && new_right_odds[1] >= 2.00 && new_right_odds[1] <= 2.4)    {
     System.out.println("PLACE TEAM ON INDEX 3 IF ALL CONDITIONS ARE MET:" + "\n" + matches[3] + "\n");     

     currentTeam = matches[3];
     currentGame = matches2[1];
     }

     else if(date_time[8] >= day && date_time[9] >= month && gameCurr_time_comp3 >= 10 && new_left_odds[2] >= 2.00 && new_left_odds[2] <= 2.4)    {
     System.out.println("PLACE TEAM ON INDEX 4 IF ALL CONDITIONS ARE MET:" + "\n" + matches[4] + "\n");     

     currentTeam = matches[4];
     currentGame = matches2[2];
     }

     else if(date_time[8] >= day && date_time[9] >= month && gameCurr_time_comp3 >= 10 && new_right_odds[2] >= 2.00 && new_right_odds[2] <= 2.4)    {
     System.out.println("PLACE TEAM ON INDEX 5 IF ALL CONDITIONS ARE MET:" + "\n" + matches[5] + "\n");     

     currentTeam = matches[5];
     currentGame = matches2[2];
     }

     else{
     System.out.println("DON\'T PLACE ANY TEAM OR GAME" + "\n");   
     }
```

Comment: welcome to SO. if you want others to help you, make it easy for them. follow this guide to write good questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: and while you are at it: maybe you want to consider fixing the code indenation

Comment: I will do that next time I ask a question thank you.

Comment: you can still edit your question

Answer (score 1):

Your code is far too long to for the simple question you ask.
It's impossible to see where I should insert my code.

So, in stead, here is how to fix your problem in a very minimalistic way

```
int a = 0;
int b = 100;
while(a < b)
{
    try{
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }catch(Exception ex){}
    a = 1; // substitute some of your logic
    b = 0; // substitute some of your logic
}
```

This program conceptually waits for two variables to have the condition `a < b`

This approach of sleeping and then re-evaluating is known as active polling. It's typically listed as an anti-(design) pattern. You should not waste resources (threads) like this.

Consider an approach where the process that calculates your values simply notifies others "Hey, my values have been updated. If you're interested check them out."